# JSF backing method and form validation

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

```
<h:commandButton value="#{msg.signupbutton}" id="registernewuser"
    action="registernewuser" execute="@form" update="reg"
    style="color:white;background-image:none;background-color:#69A74E;" />
</h:panelGrid>

<h:outputLabel for="email" value="#{msg.emailLabel}: *" />
<p:inputText id="email" value="#{userBean.emailaddr}"
    required="true" label="Email" validatorMessage="Invalid Email"
    maxlength="32" match="emailtwo" >
    <f:validateRegex
        pattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$"></f:validateRegex>
</p:inputText>
<h:message for="email" style="color:red"/>

<h:outputLabel for="emailtwo"
    value="#{msg.confirmemailLabel}: *" />
<p:inputText id="emailtwo" label="Confirm Email"
    value="#{userBean.emailTwo}" required="true"
    requiredMessage="Email is required" maxlength="32" />
<h:message for="emailtwo" style="color:red"/>
```

Hi, I have this form where I need to check that the second email `inputtext` field is the same as that of the first email `inputtext` field.  Kind of like the password match in primefaces.

On the first submission and if there are errors in other `inputtext` fields such as the username, the validation for the username will be done and the backing method `registernewuser` will not be run.

If there are no validation errors in other fields but only that `emailTwo` does not match that of email one, the method `registernewuser` will be run and the validation error will be shown on the form.

Is there a way to let the `registernewuser` to be executed even when there are errors in other fields?  I have like to show the error message "Confirm email not the same as the first email" during the first form submission.

Primefaces 3.4.2
JSF: 2.1.29

Comment: set unique ids to the h:message components and update them as well in the ajax partial update. don't you have some immediate handled model value in the form?

Comment: I had used Omnifaces for the second email match validation and somehow it resolved my issues